# Keep application & server working perfect?

Tags: swift, server

I was wondering, how do big companies do that the application and the server's response stays synchronised even when the user doesn't updates his app?

---

Like let's say I'm a user and I use the app

**App 1.0**

```
let data_name = data["data_name"]
print("Hello " + data_name + "!")
```

**Server 1.0**

```
echo('["data_name": "BOB"]');
```

Everything works fine, the app prints

> Hello BOB!

---

**But what if I update** the **app** and the **server** too, and i change the variable `data_name` to `user_name`, BUT the user doesn't update his old app?

**App 1.0**

```
let data_name = data["data_name"]
print("Hello " + data_name + "!")
```

**Server 2.0**

```
echo('["user_name": "BOB"]');
```

> ERROR: data_name is NULL

---

How does big companies deal with that?

If I don't update some app they still work perfect after a few months too..

(Btw I saw that they are able to update the app even though if the user doesn't download the update..)

Answer (score 2):

Versioned APIs. The server supports multiple versions of its API. Old versions of the app request data using the old API. New versions use the new API. It could be as simple as passing a version number as an argument to the API and the server responds accordingly.

Also note that some apps force you to update. This is so the server only needs to support the latest API.